# Query a multi-valued column for multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let me start by describing the issue. There is a field/column that is multi-valued and not atomic which I understand violates rules of normalization. The field Constituent_list can have a string like:

```
Alumni Owned/Gift Source / Committee member / Donor / Donor Advised Funds / Foundation / Major donor / Trustee Gift Source - Org.
```

These values delimited by / represent a characteristic of an Entity. So they can be a Donor, Trustee and the table that has the number of unique values goes up to 45 values. So, potentially an Entity can have 45 values that characterize it.

I want to query a table with that column. The table has thousands of rows so if a query selects 5, 10, 20 of the possible characteristics the query has to process n number of possible values for any given row to see if it meets the query condition. But if the row is already selected why test another of the values if it is already part of the record set? The following code show a selection but it's using a multi-valued string that I selected and not the single values that are in a lookup table that has the 45 values as separate rows.

```
DECLARE @P_Constituent AS nvarchar(1000)
SET @P_Constituent = 'Alumni Owned/Gift Source / Committee member / Donor / Donor Advised Funds / Foundation / Major donor / Trustee Gift Source - Org.'
SELECT *
FROM [Entity]
WHERE Constituency_List IN (@P_Constituent)
```

This is how the table looks that has the values that will be use in the query:

```
Constituency
Alumni Owned/Gift Source
Alumnus
Associated Prospect
Board member
Committee member
Corp. Foundation
Corporation
Donor
Donor Advised Funds
Estate of
Event registrant
Faculty/Staff
Family Foundation
Fellow/Post Doc
Former Employee
Former Parent
Former Student
Foundation
Friend
Fundraiser
Governmental Entity
Group/Trade Union
Headquarters
Honorary Alumnus
Institution/Educ.
Law Firm
Living Trust
Loyal donor
Major donor
Non-grad Alumnus
NYU Affiliate
Organization/Vol Hth
Other
Parent
Parent Source - Org.
Patient
Prospect
Religious
Staff
Student
Trust
Trustee Gift Source - Org.
Trustee Gift Source - Person
Vendor
```

So, what is the best way to query a table with this multi-valued column using the above table in the most efficient way?

Comment: You gave up "efficiency" when you implemented a multi-valued attribute.

Comment: Fix your data model if you want efficiency.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this is not my data model but belong to a client. But what suggestions do you have for changing it to make the query process more simple and effecient?

Answer (score 0):

You can use table-valued function `STRING_SPLIT`.

For example:

```
DECLARE @P_Constituent AS nvarchar(1000);
SET @P_Constituent = 'Alumni Owned/Gift Source / Committee member / Donor / Donor Advised Funds / Foundation / Major donor / Trustee Gift Source - Org.';

--Try it out
--SELECT TRIM(value) AS value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@P_Constituent,'/');

SELECT *
FROM [Entity]
WHERE Constituency_List IN (
     SELECT TRIM(value) AS value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@P_Constituent,'/')
)
```

Please note that `STRING_SPLIT` is available from SQL Sever Version 2016 and later.

Please read more about [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as per your need.